# WSO2 esb load balancing benefits

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, esb, high-availability

For ESB setup We have 2 nodes and a LB , wanted to understand what are the list of benefits we get if we do WOS2 load balancing , i guess the option would be worker-worker .

Can we achieve High availability with the load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

You can have both high availability and high throughput if you have 2 worker nodes.

Please note you need a manager node too, to install artifacts. Then those artifacts should be copied to worker nodes by dep-sync or rsync. But you don't need a separate node for this. One of your worker nodes can act as a manager too.

Clustering is used in below cases:

- Communication in dep-sync
- Distribited cache invalidtion (In shared registry and cache
  mediator)
- Message Store and Message processor

Comment: how is the High availability achieved with clustering , can you pls explain , If one of the node goes down and there are few http requests are being processed on that node , will those requests be transferred to node 2 and continue processing ? or there will be data loss

Comment: Requests that are already received by failed worker can't be forwarded to the other node. Those will be lost, and user will get a timeout. Then user has to resend it.

Comment: In that case any LB will forward the requests to the other active node if one node goes down , and we dont need any clustering in this case right .

Comment: If you have dep-sync, you need clustering .

Comment: so only benefit of clustering we get is deployment in the manager node sync with worked nodes , if we can manage to do the deployment manually on both the non clustered ESB nodes  , any other benfits by using clustering (worker-worker or manager-worker)

Comment: Thanks for the info, we are using one common MySQL db between these 2 ESB nodes , hope in this case it works fine without clustering .

Comment: If you use registry mounting by sharing a single database, you need clustering. Otherwise registry cache invalidation won't work. Other than that, you should be fine.

Comment: ok this is a valid point , will worker -worker clustering will be enough here ? we will not use dep-sync and manager node?  Also if i plan to use local reg instead of conf/gov then also i think we are good without clustering even though we use same MySQL DB

Comment: Yes, in that case you should be fine.

Comment: final point : If iuse conf/gov registry on shared DB  , will worker -worker clustering will be enough here ? we will not use dep-sync and manager node?

Comment: We had setup 2 ESB nodes pointing to Same MySQL DB (in WSO2_CARBON_DB section of data sources xml)
From node-1 imported CAR (with a api and reg resource-xslt) in the conf:/ location and was able to view the same from the node-2.
We imported the car file into the node-2 as well , Here we dint do any clustering  ,test interfaces from both nodes  , Can you pls explain why is it required to create clustering in this case .